# Why is `List<T>` not clonable?

Tags: c#, list

Why doesn't the .net generic type [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) offer any `Clone()` function?

Why doesn't it implement `IClonable`?

Comment: Most types don't offer a `Clone` function. Make your own :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with cloning objects and, especially the `ICloneable` interface, is that the public interface doesn't communicate the intention well.

Namely - will such `Clone` function of the `List<T>` clone contained elements as well, or just clone the list and copy the references to contained elements? Shallow copy, which copies the references and only creates the new list would be equivalent to this:

```
List<T> clone = new List<T>(originalList);
```

However, if you wanted to force all the contained elements to be cloned as well, then it would be equivalent to this:

```
List<T> clone = originalList.Select(x => (T)x.Clone()).ToList();
```

This assumes that the type `T` is implementing `ICloneable`. However, even with this solution, exact effects of code execution cannot be told in advance. What does it mean for an element `x` to clone itself? Will it be a shallow copy (offered by the `MemberwiseClone` method it inherits form `System.Object`), or will it be a deep copy. And if deep, what will happen if two objects in the list are referencing the same third object? Will that third object be copied twice or only once? And so on... you can see where this is going.

For all the reasons listed above, cloning facilities are not incorporated in the framework. It is left to custom code to decide what it means to clone an object and then implement custom code for that.

Answer (score 4):

To make a cloneable `List` type you would do:

```
public class CloneableList<T> : List<T>, ICloneable
{
    public object Clone() {
        var clone = new CloneableList<T>();
        clone.AddRange(this);
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Or this if you want it deeply cloned:

```
public class DeepCloneableList<T> : List<T>, ICloneable where T : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone() {
        var clone = new DeepCloneableList<T>();
        clone.AddRange(this.Select(x => (T)x.Clone()));
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `List<T>` does not inherit from IClonable. If you want to do a clone of a list you could do...

```
var t = new List<IClonable>();
var newList = t.Select(a=>a.Clone()).ToList();
```

Comment: mostly because you should be able to store anything in a list regardless of if the items are cloneable or not